# Duplication entry at foreign key column

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have referenced a foreign key to a primary key. Whenever I click on create new project, I am storing the project Id in the reference key but I want to store multiple projects.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even your query is not much clear that what issue you are getting but you can understand foreign key concept as per below-

If you create a foreign key in any child table and referenced it with master table means you are saying that child table can contain a value only its reference exists in parent table.

Normally in mostly cases we want to use normalization and basic concept is that we keep unique value in master table (mostly primary key) and its child rows (multiple) in its child table.

Suppose we have two tables customer and order then customer table contains unique customer but as same customer can order multiple times, so order tables may contains multiple customers.

In your case whenever you will create a new project then a new project_id will insert in master i.e. project table and its multiple sub-attributes in its child tables. Now whats the issue you are facing. Please explain.

Comment: First of all thank you , I solved the problem,  turns out the project Id being generated was the same.  Hence was getting the error. Thank you

Comment: If you feel that this answer helps you then you may choose it as accepted answer by green stick.  :)